# Excluding properties from update instead of updating whole object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, aspnetboilerplate, change-tracking

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate with Code-First Entity Framework 6 and MVC 5.

In order to update an entity, I am using `UpdateAsync`.

How can I exclude some properties from the entity before executing update?

What function should I use and is this implemented in ASP.NET Boilerplate or not yet?

I have achieved that in Entity Framework 6 as follows:

```
public virtual TEntity UpdateWithExcludeProperities(TEntity entity,string [] properities)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "entity");

    var existedEntity = SelectFromContext(entity.ID);
    if (existedEntity == null)
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Record is not found!");

    _context.Entry(existedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    foreach (var name in properities)
    {
        _context.Entry(existedEntity).Property(name).IsModified = false;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return existedEntity;
}

public virtual TEntity SelectFromContext(Guid id)
{
    TEntity entity;
    entity = DbSet<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
    return entity;
}
```

But is there any possibility to implement this code in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to do that in ASP.NET Boilerplate  as following by working with Ef core LINQ queries directly only

```
public virtual TEntity SelectFromContext(TPrimaryKey id)
{
    TEntity entity;
    entity = Repository.GetDbContext().Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
    return entity;
}

public virtual async Task<TEntity> UpdateWithExclude(TEntity entity, string[] properities)
{
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Paramter cannot be null", "entity");

        var existedEntity = SelectFromContext(entity.Id);
        if (existedEntity == null)
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Record is not found!");

        var currentValues = Repository.GetDbContext().Entry(existedEntity).CurrentValues;

        foreach (var properteyName in currentValues.PropertyNames)//make default false value for all 
        {
            var y = Repository.GetDbContext().Entry(existedEntity).Property(properteyName);
            if (!properities.Contains(y.Name))
                Repository.GetDbContext().Entry(existedEntity).Property(properteyName).IsModified = false;
        }

        Repository.GetDbContext().Entry(existedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

        Repository.GetDbContext().SaveChanges();
        var UpdatedEntity = SelectFromContext(entity.Id);
        return await Task.FromResult(UpdatedEntity);
}
```

Comment: if you use this code in AspNet Boilerplate, you will break `UnitOfWork` rules. This is a hack

Answer (score 0):

you are on the wrong path!
it's very simple to update an entity with the specified fields.

1- Create a DTO.

2- Configure mapping

3- Get entity and map DTO to entity.

Checkout my example. In this example `Student` entity has 3 properties. In the `StudentAppService` `UpdateOnlyNameOfStudent()` method, we update only `Name` field of Student. And notice that I even didn't run `_studentRepository.Update(student)` because AspNet Boilerplate commits the changes when the method ends (See [automatic save change](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#automatically-saving-changes))

**StudentDto.cs**

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Student))]
public class StudentDto: EntityDto<long>
{
     public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

---

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student: Entity
{
     public string Name { get; set; }  

     public int SchoolNumber { get; set; }  

     public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }  
}
```

---

**StudentAppService.cs**

```
public class StudentAppService : IStudentAppService 
{
    private readonly IRepository<Student> _studentRepository;


    public RoleAppService(IRepository<Student> studentRepository)
    {
       _studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public override async void UpdateOnlyNameOfStudent(StudentDto input)
    {
        var student = _studentRepository.Get(input.Id);
        ObjectMapper.Map(input, student);
    }

    /*
    public override async void UpdateOnlyNameOfStudent_Alternative(StudentDto input)
    {
        var student = _studentRepository.Get(input.Id);
        student.Name = input.Name;            
    }
    */
}
```

AspNet Boilerplate uses AutoMapper to map objects. See [Object To Object Mapping](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Object-To-Object-Mapping)

Comment: but the generated sql query BY AbpBoilerPlate  AS pseudo code will be 
UPDATE Student 
SET Name='NewEnteredName',SchoolNumber='OldValue',RegisterDate='OldValue' WHERE ID='OldValue'
but what IF i want my generated  SQL query TO be 
UPDATE Student 
SET Name='NewEnteredName' WHERE WHERE ID='OldValue'

that's what i meant in my question to make generated dynamic  update clause have only updated fields is that possible

Comment: in this point, ASP.NET Boilerplate has nothing to do with your SQL query. The Entity Framework generates that SQL query and it's being generated by the changes made on your entity. We have changed only name field with the help of AutoMapper. So only 1 field has to be updated. You can try manual mapping in your code. I added an alternative update for UpdateOnlyNameOfStudent